# Trouble with removing nodes in Python double linked list

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have been trying to create a double linked list in Python for a little while now, but am having trouble with a few methods within my `LinkedList` class. I would like my `removeFront` and `removeRear` methods to return the value that is removed, but I cannot get this to work. With a test list, the if I enter some value x into a node and try to remove it, x is not returned.

I believe the idea for removing a node is to cut it out of the list by connecting its next node with its previous node, but have a feeling my attempt at this is fundamentally flawed.

I am also trying to implement a `pop` method (to remove a specific element in the list) but am not sure where to start. Any advice to nudge me in the right direction here would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None

class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.front = None
        self.rear = None

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.front is None and self.rear is None

    def addFront(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        if self.front is None:
            self.front = new_node
            self.rear = self.front
            self.front.prev = None
            self.rear.next = None
        else:
            self.front.prev = new_node
            new_node.next = self.front
            self.front = new_node
            self.front.prev = None

    def addRear(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        if self.front is None:
            self.rear = new_node
            self.front = self.rear
            self.front.prev = None
            self.rear.next = None
        else:
            self.rear.next = new_node
            new_node.prev = self.rear
            self.rear = new_node
            self.rear.next = None

    def removeFront(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            return None
        else:
            removed = self.front
            self.front.prev = self.front
            self.front.prev.next = None
            return removed

    def removeRear(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            return None
        else:
            removed = self.rear
            self.rear.prev = self.rear
            self.rear.prev.next = None
            return removed

    def pop(self, index):
        # TODO: How to implement?
        pass

    def size(self):
        current = self.front
        count = 0
        while current is not None:
            count += 1
            current = current.next
        return count
```

Comment: Is removeFront/Rear supposed to return the *value* that is removed, or the node itself? Currently you're returning the node.

Comment: Eek, I was indeed trying to return the value. This turned out to be at the root of the problem. I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick code review:

- `Node.__init__()` is correct.
- `LinkedList.__init__()` is correct.
- `LinkedList.isEmpty()` is correct.
- `LinkedList.size()` is correct.

---

Here is how to implement `LinkedList.removeFront()` properly:

```
    def removeFront(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            return None
        else:
            removed = self.front.data
            self.front = self.front.next
            if self.front is None:  # List size was 1
                self.rear = None
            else:
                self.front.prev = None
            return removed
```

I will leave the implementation of `removeRear()` as an exercise to you. The logic is symmetrical to `removeFront()`.

---

`LinkedList.addFront()` is correct, but can be simplified:

```
    def addFront(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        if self.front is None:
            self.front = new_node
            self.rear = new_node
            #self.front.prev = None  # Already None
            #self.rear.next  = None  # Already None
        else:
            self.front.prev = new_node
            new_node.next = self.front
            self.front = new_node
            #self.front.prev = None  # Already None
```

Your `LinkedList.addRear()` is correct, but can be simplified in the same way.

---

You asked about how to implement `LinkedList.pop()`. It will be a tricky one. You have to consider multiple cases:

- What if the list has exactly one element?
- What if the node to be removed is at the front?
- What if the node to be removed is at the rear?
- What if the node to be removed is strictly in the middle?

Comment: Have you tried `removeFront` in case that list contains only one node? It will first update `self.front` to `self.front.next` which is `None`. Then on the following line it will try to execute `self.front.prev = None` which naturally fails since `self.front` is `None` at that point. On top of that `self.rear` doesn't get updated.

Comment: @niemmi Oops, thank you. I will make the necessary corrections.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and the help with my question. I managed to get everything working except for the `pop` method. I'll try to get it working with what you've mentioned in mind.

Comment: You're welcome! Try implementing `pop()` as much as possible by yourself. When you have an algorithm sketch, even if it's not complete or correct, feel free to post a new question

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of `removeFront` with comments:

```
def removeFront(self):
    if self.isEmpty():
        return None

    # Store data so that it can be returned
    data = self.front.data
    if self.front == self.rear:
        # List contains one item, set front & rear to initial state
        self.front = self.rear = None
    else:
        # More than one item
        self.front = self.front.next    # Set front to point next item
        self.front.prev = None          # Front doesn't have previous item

    return data
```

`removeRear` works exactly with the same logic.

In order to implement `pop` you need to consider three different cases:

- Front is being removed
- Rear is being removed
- Node between front and rear is being removed

No matter what case is in question you still need to find the right node to remove. You can do this in a loop while advancing in the list. Once you have found the correct node you can utilize `removeFront` or `removeRear` in case it's first or last node. If node falls somewhere between you need cut it from previous & next node and join the remaining nodes together.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Regarding `pop`, using a loop makes a lot of sense. Traversing the loop to find the desired piece of data (assuming it is somewhere in the middle of the list) seems straightforward enough. I suppose the challenge is in stitching the list back together. I will give it a go.

Comment: @user243253 You can just do traversing and once you've found the node you want to remove figure which category it belongs to and take appropriate action. Note that when you remove a node somewhere between there's no need to update links on the removed node, making sure that remaining nodes have correct links is enough.